# Spark Structured streaming Writing to Kinesis Fiehose

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-kinesis-firehose, spark-structured-streaming

Is there any API/ way to integrate Spark Streaming with Amazon kinesis firehose. I am able to integrate with Kafka and Sockets but  I am unable to write to amazon kinesis firehose .

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kinesis-integration.html

Comment: i'm working on spark structured streaming,above mentioned link talks about spark streaming.